# Replacing elements in a tube amplifier

Tags: amplifier, schematics, sound, guitar-amplifier, tube

I assembled a tube amplifier.According to the specified scheme (Old Russian radio "**Record 66**"). 
[image: Record 66]

1.What is the function of capacitors **C9** and **C8** ?

2.What will change the capacity of these parts? Will the sound be changed ?

3.I made this amplifier for an electric guitar. What would you recommend for its modification?

Comment: Question 1 is hard to answer without knowing how much you already know about frequency response. Can you find the corner frequencies of the filters they form?

Question 2 is a bit unclear. Do you mean: "What will change with the capacity of these parts?"

Question 3 is very general and challenging to answer usefully.

Comment: If you're going to change these capacitors, use non-polarized capacitors rated for at least the same voltage as the ones in the kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C9: think of it as a low-pass filter: the higher the frequency of a signal, the more it will be "shorted" through C9, and the less it will be coupled through Tp2.

If you increase C9's capacity, you'll cut off at a lower frequency.

C8: AC-couple high-frequency components to ground – its function isn't 100% clear to me from the schematic. I wouldn't change it – that's there's a potentiometer right next to it.

Comment: You've got a good moniker. Note that "Markus Müller" (from the Austrian Academy of Sciences) recently was part of a team publishing: [The Measurement Postulates of Quantum Mechanics are Redundant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11060). Interesting stuff.

Comment: Thanks! Theoretical Physics… hope my math suffices to get the gist of what my Namensvetter (literally: Name Cousin, meaning namesake) wrote :) (Fun Fact: There's quite a lot of Müllers (transliterates directly to miller even in modern German) in German-speaking Europe – it's the most common name if you don't throw all the M{ea}{iy}[e]r (from lat. *major domus*, the guy administrating a farm for their aristocratic or clerical owner of the land) or all the Schmi[e]{dt}[t] (modern form is Schmied, engl. smith) in the same statistical bin.)

Comment: I spend my idle time studying M-theory. My teacher is Dr. Sirag. It's a mess for me, as I'm struggling through reflection spaces that mirror bosons and fermions, packing spheres for error-correction coding in (10 and) 11-dimensions, etc. I keep track of articles like this and just happened to note the name similarity! (I spend more time with string theory than electronics because the math is actually enjoyable.)

Comment: I hear you! Wouldn't be teaching Basics of Stochastics to EE students if the math wasn't fun :D

Answer (score 1):

C9 across the output transformer makes a low pass filter - it shorts out high frequencies. Probably done here to reduce noise as radio broadcasts have limited high frequency response (FM up to 15kHz, AM up to 10kHz IIRC).

C8 with its potentiometer injects high frequency components of the output signal back to the grid. This is the "treble" tone control. If you turn the pot to one way, it shunts C8 to ground and then there is no feedback (high frequencies are not reduced). if you turn it the other way, then maximum amount of HF is fed back, reducing the HF response.